# Using Sigmatel STAC 92XX on Windows 7 RTM x64, cannot get 5.1 surround sound to work

Tags: windows-7, audio, surround-sound, sigmatel

I have a Dell XPS 420.  I've installed Windows 7 RTM (x64)

I have this audio device:  SIGMATEL STAC 92XX C-Major HD Audio

I have tried using the windows 7 basic driver, and also the Vista 64-bit driver from Dell's website (details):

```
Date: 10/29/2007
Version: 6.10.0.5511, A04 
File Size: 7 MB
```

With both drivers, I get normal stereo sound from the driver, but my 5.1 surround sound doesn't work.  Has anyone experienced this?  Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

similar problem here. Except for me that center and the back speakers are mixed up. If i test the 5.1 sound in windows 7 these speakers are wrong. Have a Dell MP1530.

the only idea i have is to check the pin asignment in the registry on:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\
{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\PinConfigOverrideVerbs
```

But here's my problem... i don't know how to edit these hex values properly to fix it.

(the 0000-Value varies for each system/driver)

for you 'Roy Rico':
Setting -> View Category -> Hardware and Sound -> Sigmatel Audio 
.. then plugin your speakers and it sould display you that its set up. Maybe restart too.

Comment: i upgraded to a new system, so this is no longer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the type of speaker system from 2.1 to 5.1? Go to the icon right click and go to playback devices, then choose the device and configure. That's what ended up making surround sound work properly for me.